# How do I get the tag parent with Joomla 4?

Tags: joomla-4.x, tags, filter

I'm using Joomla 4 and need to use the *new* API to get tags which have a specific parent. (I am already able to do it with the legacy API using the $tag->parent_id). It seems that the new API doesn't have that attribute by default.
I have a hunch that I need to pass a filter along to Tag::tags(); but have no idea how to do it. Can anybody help please?